# EncryptedFile, openFileInput() no encuentra archivo

Tags: android

Al asignar a un FileInputStream con encryptedFile.openFileInput() siempre retorna -1 si quiero leerlo(fis.read()), pero si cambio por ejemplo a FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(archivo) no tengo problemas al leer(fis.read() funciona bien), según documentación es simple pero algo no ocurre y no logro detectarlo, gracias.

//Encripta bien

```
File archivo = new File(getCacheDir(), "archivo.jpg");
KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC;
String masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(keyGenParameterSpec);

EncryptedFile encryptedFile = new EncryptedFile.Builder(archivo, this, masterKeyAlias,
EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB).build();

byte[] fileContent = byteArrayArchivo.toByteArray();

OutputStream os = encryptedFile.openFileOutput();
os.write(fileContent);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

//No logra desencriptar

```
File archivo = new File(getCacheDir(), "archivo.jpg");
KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC;
String masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(keyGenParameterSpec);

EncryptedFile encryptedFile = new EncryptedFile.Builder(archivo, this, masterKeyAlias,
EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB).build();

FileInputStream fis = encryptedFile.openFileInput();
int nextByte = fis.read();// siempre -1
```

Comment: la segunda parte no me parece que este desencriptando, ¿estas seguro que ese es el código?

Comment: Cuando fis.read() retorna distinto de -1 se debe ocupar un outputstream en un ciclo while para escribir el byte, esa parte no la agregue por que como siempre da -1 nunca entra al ciclo y no escribe el archivo desencriptado.